# How to send mail from my mac using local xampp with php contacts form

Tags: php, html, xampp, smtp, phpmailer

i have xampp 7.1 installed on my 2016 macbook pro. I have a php contacts form in my source folder which is rendered successfully by chrome along with my html. However, I need to configure the smtp settings to test some functionality locally from my mac.

I found a php.ini in the xampp etc folder that contains some mail function. 
[image: php.ini mail function screenshot]

I found other articles which reference phpmailer but since they were a few years old i figured newer versions of xampp for mac may have all the functionality builtin.

Can I modify this php.ini file to use a gmail mailbox as a recipient? How so?

thanks in advance

Here is a copy paste of the mail function :

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail 
-t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra 
parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the 
value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script 
followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=On

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, 
to address and headers
;mail.log =
```

---

Comment: Screenshots of code **suck**.  Please include the actual text from the relevant code in your question.

Comment: just added the code for the mail function portion of the php.ini file which i assume is where i need to enter the providers smtp settings. However, I am not too sure what to enter or if this is even the place to enter the settings - based on some research i believe it is. thanks for your time. FYI, i am a sysadmin(datacenter deployments) but complete newb programmer.

Comment: @tobe1424: It's not the right thing to do editing your question with the code you finally worked out thought .. instead, if you'd like to share your solution then post it as an answer. You can even mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @tobe1424: I rolled back to the last revision; You can copy the code from the revision history you just pasted, then put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is sending mails from your app server to your own gmail inbox, you don't have to modify these settings; use [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is an easier way. So let's start step by step.

- 1. Allowing [Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) -or- configure for [`XOAUTH2`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2); credits to @Synchro.
- 2. Download [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and extract `PHPMailer.php`, `SMTP.php` and `Exception.php` to your `xampp/htdocs` folder

     [image]
- 3. Write a sample send mail page `send.php`: (modify to your real account)

     ```
     <?php
     require_once('SMTP.php');
     require_once('PHPMailer.php');
     require_once('Exception.php');

     use \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
     use \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

     $mail=new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions

     try {
         //settings
         $mail->SMTPDebug=2; // Enable verbose debug output
         $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
         $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
         $mail->SMTPAuth=true; // Enable SMTP authentication
         $mail->Username='YourAccount@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
         $mail->Password='YourPassword'; // SMTP password
         $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';
         $mail->Port=465;

         $mail->setFrom('sender@whatever.com', 'optional sender name');

         //recipient
         $mail->addAddress('YourAccount@gmail.com', 'optional recipient name');     // Add a recipient

         //content
         $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
         $mail->Subject='Here is the subject';
         $mail->Body='This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
         $mail->AltBody='This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

         $mail->send();

         echo 'Message has been sent';
     } 
     catch(Exception $e) {
         echo 'Message could not be sent.';
         echo 'Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
     }

     ?>
     ```
- 4. When all above are ready, issue the url of `send.php` on your app server to send the example email
- 5. Base on this example, you can write a contact form for real use. You might also want to change the location of `PHPMailer`, then you should modify the path in the example code to point to the new location where they are.

Comment: This is indeed much better than trying to configure the mail server in XAMPP, but there are some small mistakes here that are not present in the examples provided with PHPMailer. You don't need to enable less secure apps - you can use XOAUTH2, though you really need composer to use that. Gmail won't let you set arbitrary from addresses. Because you did not `use` the PHPMailer `Exception` class, you're catching global exceptions, not just PHPMailer exceptions.

Comment: Thank you, Ken, Synchro. I will give this a shot right away!

Comment: I was able to accomplish my goal. Thanks again. One last question. I understand this is my lab environment. How would this work once I publish my site with lets say, go daddy. Do I keep this phpmailer solution or should i use something else?

Comment: @tobe1424: I'm not familiar with GoDaddy's services. Normally if these are put on a virtual host should be just fine. Use relative paths in your code; you might have to configure XOAUTH2 for that host also.

Comment: I used godaddy as an example. However, I meant to say a web hosting provider. no vps or hosted server environment. Just a good ole simple web hosting platform like network solutions or godaddy. I know they have php engines but I am wondering if i will need to restructure how the php contacts form works once i move the site to the hosting provider.

Comment: Then you’d have to test.

Comment: 10-4. I got the mail to to work in my hosting environment so thanks again! However, what works is the 'send mail' feature. I receive the test email on my gmail account but it shows up in my inbox with the sample code in the //content section. Not the info i typed in my html input fields where the user is suppose to enter their details. Also, as soon as i land on the send.php page an email is sent automatically without me invoking the submit button. Any ideas on how the html input values can be used in the email and why an email sends automatically upon landing on the page? Thanks a million

Comment: This is just a example of how to send the mail. When you are constructing a contact form, you might not visit this page directly, rather, use a html form like `<form action=' .. ` in the contact form page with a `submit` button. There are several ways you can design it, but really, you'd have to put some effort on how to build a website and if you encounter other problems, post your questions if which are not already answered.

Comment: Hi Ken, completely off topic here; I am curious to know why you previously recommended changing the location of phpmailer. Is there a security concern?

Comment: @tobe1424: Not really, they are just classes without instantiation and do nothing. If the attackers issue that url to your host, they'll receive a blank page instead of a 404 error page, and they can make a guess what's on your host. It's no big deal but usually you'll want to keep the attackers know as less as possible of the scence behind. It's more of the maintainability of a well-structured directory hierarchy.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks. Here is the code i ended up using for my php contacts page. i just uploaded my contacts.php form to the public_html dir and it works seamlessly from a users perspective - I receive emails